# How to stop a bunch of processes on unix fast?

Tags: linux, shell, process, kill

How to stop a bunch of processes on unix fast.

I can use `ps`/`top`, `kill`.

If the number of processes is very large, I use shell script.
Are there other ways, only one or two unix commands can do it well ?

Comment: Do you have common name prefix for your processes?

Comment: The danger here is that when you start killing processes fast, you might kill something you didn't intend to kill.

Comment: telinit 0, or kill -9 1 works well for killing ALL the processes...

Answer (score 10):

My choice is [`pkill/pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill)

Comment: Great! Just to give an example: If you are looking to kill all curl processes, first run `pgrep -a curl` to look at all the processes that will be killed by `pkill`. If everything looks good, use `pkill curl`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little on-line bash script I use:

```
ps auxwww | grep -v grep | grep -i $1 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

I kills all processes whose name contains the first parameter (case insensitive). The breakdown of each part is:

- `ps auxwww` prints all processes with very wide "command" field
- `grep -v grep` is there to exclude itself from the killing
- `grep -i $1` matches all lines that contain the first parameter
- `awk '{print $2}'` grabs all the process ids
- `xargs kill -9` kills all the selected processes

Comment: +1 Love a good pipeline, especially one using `xargs`.

Comment: i prefer to use `fgrep`(no regex)

Comment: This script is overly complex compared to `pkill -9 -f $1`. Also, don't advise using signal 9 (KILL). It is a last resort way of stopping a process, not one that should be used routinely.

Answer (score 1):

Psdoom is really the only way to kill a process.  http://psdoom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

[Very Fast Way to Kill Multiple Processes (without having to write a script)](http://www.kinglazy.com/kill-running-processes-fast-on-linux-unix-aix-sunos-hpux-systems.htm)

```
USAGE: ./autokill.kl.sh <proc-name> => This will give you 5 seconds to change your mind and control-C out of the program.

USAGE: ./autokill.kl.sh <proc-name> now => This will immediately kill all processes matching the string/pattern you specified!!!

MODEL: ./autokill.kl.sh httpd

MODEL: ./autokill.kl.sh httpd now

MODEL: ./autokill.kl.sh httpd view => This will only show you the list of processes matching the pattern you specified.
```

Script can be directly downloaded [here](http://www.kinglazy.com/kill-multiple-processes-fast-on-any-unix-system.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I really prefer using the pgrep/pkill command ad here is an example:

```
[root@testrhel7 ~]# pgrep -l http
2967 httpd
2968 httpd
2969 httpd
2970 httpd
2971 httpd
2972 httpd
[root@testrhel7 ~]#
[root@testrhel7 ~]# pkill -e http
httpd killed (pid 2967)
httpd killed (pid 2968)
httpd killed (pid 2969)
httpd killed (pid 2970)
httpd killed (pid 2971)
httpd killed (pid 2972)
[root@testrhel7 ~]#
```

Of course You can use a for cycle:

```
[root@testrhel7 ~]# ps -ef  |grep http| grep -v grep
root       2989      1  0 16:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache     2990   2989  0 16:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache     2991   2989  0 16:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache     2992   2989  0 16:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache     2993   2989  0 16:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache     2994   2989  0 16:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
[root@testrhel7 ~]#

[root@testrhel7 ~]# for i in $(ps -ef | awk '/http/ {print $2}'); do kill -9 $i; done
```

I hope that was helpful, happy killing.